# Join two queries together with default values of 0 if empty in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have seen some close answers and I have been trying to adapt them to Access 2013, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I have two queries:

First query returns

```
 original_staff_data
    Month
    Year
    staff_uid
    staff_abbrev
    employee_name
    staff_salary
```

It pulls this from tables staff, and salary_by_month and employee_name and number_of_days_at_spec_building (this records where they check in when they work)

```
transaction_data_by_staff.total
    Month
    Year
    staff_uid
    total_revenue
    totat_profit
```

this also pulls information from staff, but sums up over multiple dates in a transaction table creating a cumulative value for each staff_uid so I can't combine the two queries directly.

My problem is I want to create a query that brings results from both.  However, not all staff members in Q1 will be in Q2 every day/week/month (vacations, etc) and since I want to ultimately create a final results:

```
Final_Result
    Month
    Year
    staff_uid
    staff_abbrev
    employee_name
    staff_salary
    total_revenue
    total_profit
```

The SQL:

```
SELECT
  original_staff_data.*
, transaction_data_by_staff.total_rev
, transaction_data_by_staff.total_profit
FROM transaction_data_by_staff
RIGHT JOIN original_staff_data
ON (
  transaction_data_by_staff.year = original_staff_data.year
  AND transaction_data_by_staff.month = original_staff_data.month
) WHERE transaction_data_by_staff.[staff_uid] = [original_staff_data].[staff_uid];
```

I would like it if there is no revenue or profit that month from that employee, it makes those values 0.  I have tried join (specifically RIGHT join with Q1 as the RIGHT join) and it doesn't seem to work, I still only get the subset.  There are originally in the original_staff_data query 750 entries so therefore there should be in the final query 750 entries, I am only getting 252, which is the total in transaction_data_by_staff.  Any clue on how the ACCESS 2013 SQL should look?

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the link by stuff_uid to the ON clause, like this:

```
SELECT original_staff_data.*, transaction_data_by_staff.total_rev, transaction_data_by_staff.total_profit
FROM transaction_data_by_staff RIGHT JOIN original_staff_data ON (transaction_data_by_staff.year = original_staff_data.year) AND (transaction_data_by_staff.month = original_staff_data.month)
AND (((transaction_data_by_staff.[staff_uid])=[original_staff_data].[staff_uid]));
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  That was the correct answer.  I had tried it before, but for some reason it didn't work (probably was screwing around with the other statements).  Thanks again.